# Delete the original big size image after upload and leave only 3 images crunched by media gallery

Tags: posts, images, plugin-gravity-forms

I need to know is it possible to somehow erase the original image uploaded via Gravity form : post image - post field?! With the situation now I receive 4 images. 1 original (can be whatever user has on his PC - up to 4 MB which clutters the server) and 3 which Wordpress creates according to specifications (thumbnail, medium, large). I would like to have the ability when user uploads the "original big image" to be deleted upon upload and be left with 3 remaining in media gallery?!. It will dramatically improve the storage on my server.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image' );
function delete_fullsize_image( $metadata )
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink( $full_image_path );

    return $metadata;
}
```

Not 100% sure everything will work ok without the main image, but it does the trick. You wont be able to regenerate the thumbnails / sizes as the main image is required for this.

Edit: I just re-read the question, I noticed you are wanting this to only happen when people upload via a form. Must be early for me, the above code will delete any attachment uploaded. I guess all you would need to do is find someway of checking if the upload was via your gravity form. Hope it helps you anyway.

Comment: in terms of never being able to 'regenerate' thumbnails since you need the original, is there a way to rename the 'large' image so that it is seen as the original?  ie you'd have image100x100.jpg, image300x300.jp and image.jpg (where the last one is maxed out a the 'large' dimensions