# Delete original image - keep thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

I'm using a lot of thumbnails but never the original file. To save space, I'd like to prevent the original from being saved on disk but only keep a thumbnail of 100px. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: could it be an idea perhaps to not upload large images in the first place?

Comment: Not an option as the submissions are crowd sourced :)

Comment: Would a cron script that goes through and periodically deletes the originals be an option?

Comment: please see my answer to the same question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17719/delete-the-original-big-size-image-after-upload-and-leave-only-3-images-crunched/22605#22605

Comment: If you already have some images and discover this later, use this extension: http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails It calls the hook used in the answers by Cristian and SimonSimCity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image' );
function delete_fullsize_image( $metadata )
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink( $full_image_path );

    return $metadata;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! The only (minor) problem I have is that when I look at the Media Library it doesn't show images as the full images has (obviously) been deleted. Is there a way to set the thumbnail as the Media Library Icon? Example: http://i.imgur.com/koijq.png (top is using your method, bottom is the original without deletion)

Comment: If you try a cmd refresh I thought WP was clever enough to use another version. I used this method a while ago so can't remember. I'd have to play around with it. Sorry I dont have a direct answer now!

Comment: If this is 'just' about deleting those giant 16 MPix images end-end-users might upload, another version might be to copy a somewhat small thumbnail into the full former name. That way, still the space is 95%ish saved, no one can access the fullres (since it's gone), yet Media Library showing will still work... (?)

Answer (score 4):

I foud another solution in the web. It's based on the one accepted here, but it takes it even further.

The one, accepted here, removes the main-image and goes on. The solution I found replaces the original image by the image generated for "large". It just goes on without replacing if this image-resolution is not defined.

This way it is ensured that every script, relying on the original image, will still work as before - for example the thumnail regeneration.

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-automatically-use-resized-image-instead-of-originals

**EDIT:**

@dalbaeb pointed me to an issue written in the comments on the blog-post. I rewrote the code based on the API instead of the solution provided there. It's not that much of a difference, but just to use the same function calls as in the API ;)

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {
    // if there is no large image : return
    if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data;

    // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
    $large_image_filename = $image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

    // Do what wordpress does in image_downsize() ... just replace the filenames ;)
    $image_basename = wp_basename($uploaded_image_location);
    $large_image_location = str_replace($image_basename, $large_image_filename, $uploaded_image_location);

    // delete the uploaded image
    unlink($uploaded_image_location);

    // rename the large image
    rename($large_image_location, $uploaded_image_location);

    // update image metadata and return them
    $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
    $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
    unset($image_data['sizes']['large']);

    // Check if other size-configurations link to the large-file
    foreach($image_data['sizes'] as $size => $sizeData) {
        if ($sizeData['file'] === $large_image_filename)
            unset($image_data['sizes'][$size]);
    }

    return $image_data;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'replace_uploaded_image');
```

**EDIT2:**

I had a problem with the code on one client where another size-configuration linked to the large-file. I updated the code accordingly. If you have any kind of problems with it, drop me a mail.

Comment: Thanks for posting an alternative! Although 1) the solution appears to be buggy as per the comments after the article; and 2) it's always good to post the code directly in the answer, as the linked article could always disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @dalbaeb. I've updated my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a plugin because I had the same problem. You can download it from [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-original-image/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I still needed to solve this issue, this may have worked for new images when I used it in functions.php but I did have some issues and images becoming unusable and I also couldn't harness this to update existing images. I had about 2000 existing images I needed to go through them all and make all ofthe old big images smaller. I created a page on the front end that only an admin can access and used this code.

The big difference here is that instead of deleting the OG image and renaming the 'large' image to the OG name. (This did not work for me, I lost quite a few images trying this method) So instead I copied the large image and named the copy the same as the OG image. Hence the big image gets overwritten by the smaller 'large' image. Also on the front end, I had to change how the metadata gets updated.

**Test this on individual posts first, be sure this works for you before changing numposts to -1. I stupidly lost about 100 images trying to run the original code without carefully checking the results first.**

FRONT END CODE TO UPDATE EXISTING IMAGES:

```
function replace_uploaded_image_frontend($image_data, $attachment_id) {

 // if there is no large image : return
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

  //Original code was delete OG file and rename the large file to the OG name. This means you no longer have the large size image. So...
  //Instead I want to take the large file and make a copy and overwrite it over the large file.
    $file_to_be_copied = $large_image_location;
    $copied_file_name = $uploaded_image_location;
  //make a copy of the large image and name that the title of the original image
    if (!copy($file_to_be_copied, $copied_file_name)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    }  
    fixImageMeta($attachment_id );

}

    function fixImageMeta($attach_id) {

            $file = get_attached_file($attach_id);
            if (!empty($file)) {
                $info = getimagesize($file);
                $meta = array (
                    'width' => $info[0],
                    'height' => $info[1],
                    'hwstring_small' => "height='{$info[1]}' width='{$info[0]}'",
                    'file' => basename($file),
                    'sizes' => array(),         // thumbnails etc.
                    'image_meta' => array(),    // EXIF data
                );
                update_post_meta($attach_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta);
            }
    }


          $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
        'p' => 12926,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        /*'date_query'     => array(
            'after' => array(
                'year'  => 2016,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'before' => array(
                'year'  => 2016,
                'month' => 6,
                'day'   => 30,
            ),
        ),*/
        'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $mypost){

        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $mypost->ID );
        echo '<br>Attach ID: ' . $attachment_id . ' ';
        $unfiltered = false;
        $image_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered );
        print_r($image_data);
        replace_uploaded_image_frontend($image_data, $attachment_id);

    }
```

This of course ran into errors several times, I imagine due to some corrupt images. So after trying to go through them all at once and getting errors, I then had to spend some time going through date ranges to be sure I got all of them updated.

CODE FOR NEW IMAGES, In functions.php

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {
      // if there is no large image : return
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

  //Instead I want to take the large file and make a copy and overwrite it over the original file.
    $file_to_be_copied = $large_image_location; 
    $copied_file_name = $uploaded_image_location;
  //make a copy of the large image and name that the title of the original image
    if (!copy($file_to_be_copied, $copied_file_name)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    }

  // update image metadata and return them
  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];

  return $image_data;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above don't seem to work anymore. I slightly modified the code and the example below works for WordPress 5.5

````
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {
    // if there is no large image : return
    if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['2048x2048'])) return $image_data;

    // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_image_location = dirname($upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $image_data['file']) . '/' . $image_data['original_image'];
    
    // delete the uploaded image
    unlink($uploaded_image_location);

    unset($image_data['original_image']);

    return $image_data;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'replace_uploaded_image');```
````

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress disable upload image original

Tested wordpress 5.6

By https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626139/wordpress-removing-original-image-after-resize

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {
      // if there is no large image : return
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  // $large_image_location = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file']; // ** This only works for new image uploads - fixed for older images below.
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

  // delete the uploaded image
  unlink($uploaded_image_location);

  // rename the large image
  rename($large_image_location,$uploaded_image_location);

  // update image metadata and return them
  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
  unset($image_data['sizes']['large']);

  return $image_data;
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the solutions above is that the unlinked image is the scaled image from the 'big_image_size_threshold'. (since WP 5.3)
If you add:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

to your functions.php, the solution works!

Answer (score 0):

Found a plugin that do the job very easily [Imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/). Also can resize the original image to prefered size too.