# Limit dimensions of "Full" size images

Tags: functions, images, media

Is there a way to limit the dimensions of the full size uploaded image (made normally through the Media library)?

I have clients that upload huge images files with resolutions sometimes greater than 5000 x 5000. They don't quite understand why Wordpress/websites have a hard time with these images.

Limiting "Full" size images seems like a great solution. Is it possible via `functions.php`?

Comment: I know there is a way to do this as I've seen some Plugins that allow this feature, I will have a look into it if no one gives you an answer

Comment: I'd love to do it manually, but I've just discovered this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/

Comment: I have the solutions I think, I will post it

Comment: We have used info from this [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) page to set img sizes for media (although you set them also in the back-end in `Settings/Media` ) and used this [wpse answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69287) to keep the folder on the server 'clean and uncluttered'. For us it works like a charm and the client is also satisfied with the results.

Comment: Imsanity plugin is good for sure, but if you want to do handle both image optimization and size limiting, I find https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/  is a better option now they recently also added image resizing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

So I've found this [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) in the CodeX. Basically by adding the code below it should automatically resize an image :)

Code:

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( 'cool_image.jpg' ); // Return an implementation that extends WP_Image_Editor

if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
    $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
    $image->save( 'new_image.jpg' );
}
```

I don't know exactly if this will work but I'm sure if you look in the link I've gave you then you should be able to find it there.

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this in quora , if anyone has any other method to resize especially old uploaded images ,

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','ad_limit_media_file_max_size'); 
function ad_limit_media_file_max_size($image_data) { 
    if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['large'])) return $image_data; 
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
    $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file']; 
    $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/")); 
    $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['large']['file']; 
    unlink($uploaded_image_location); 
    rename($large_image_location,$uploaded_image_location); 
    $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width']; 
    $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height']; 
    unset($image_data['sizes']['large']); 
    return $image_data; 
}
```

Quora link:
https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-a-child-theme-in-WordPress-that-loads-faster-than-its-parent
Good luck