# Upload an image and replace it with a custom image size

Tags: uploads, images

My aim is to upload an image and completely replace the original source image with a [custom image size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), as if the custom image sized file was the uploaded image.

For example, I have custom image size `wpse`, and I want to replace the original image completely with this file upon upload.

How is this possible?

Potential approach could be to hook into the upload process, edit the `guid` key in the `wp_posts` table with the URL of the `wpse` image, then delete the source uploaded file. I'm sure there are other values which needs to be updated.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking... Are you saying you have an image that is already uploaded that you don't want to delete from the database in order to preserve it's id but instead you want to phsyically replace the image that the database entry refers to with a new image that has your custom image size `wpse` applied? If so, why can't you just delete the existing, upload the new (with custom image size) then re-attach the new image to the post that the old image was attached to? Interested to know more...

Comment: So replacing the full size image with a specific image size, right? Like this question »[Automatically replace original uploaded image with large image size](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/63707/22534)« I suppose.

Comment: @ialocin while keeping the same ID from how the last paragraph makes it sound. I imagine she also wants the other image sizes gone too. There's something [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136131/7355) that works with featured images but the whole scenario seems unpractical.

Comment: @userabuser Here is some further clarification. Currently when you upload an image, WordPress will create image sizes. So you end up with the original image, and a couple of extra files based on how many image sizes you set. Now, my aim is to *replace* the original uploaded file with a custom image size as soon as it is uploaded and delete the original one from the server. To explain my aim in simple terms. I upload an image, it creates a custom image size 'wpse', **deletes** the original source image, and makes the 'wpse' image the *main* image as if that image was the original uploaded one.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Not exactly sure what the goal is, but you might be right.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The reason why I need this is because I'm working on a platform which uploads tons of images constantly and only needs a 32x32 version of the images. So there is no need to have thousands of large images stored when I only need a tiny one. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ChristineCooper If I'm not completely misunderstanding you, then the question I linked does that.

Comment: @ChristineCooper There's [this that works with featured images](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136131/7355) and then there's [this that works with post types entirely](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131835/7355). The latter one I use on most my websites to cut down on clutter. Will either of those work for you or - how do you differentiate between that 32x32 image and the rest of images on the site?

Comment: @ialocin Yes yes! It looks like it. Sorry, I did not see your comment edit. I will have to confirm and check that Q&A first but by the description, it sounds like my gig! I will update soon when I have tested it.

Comment: No worries and lots of success!

Comment: @ialocin I can confirm that this is the correct answer. Had to adjust the code somewhat but it works! Didn't think I would get a good solution to this, thanks for linking it!!

Comment: We are here to help each other, so do not mention it and my pleasure!

Comment: We're closing this one and I have bountied the answer on that other question for the great solution. Thanks everyone again...! =D